# JMeter - How to get data for assertion from multiple csv file in jsr 223 assertion

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have to assert HTTP JSON Response using JSR 223 assertion. The validation data are stored in multiple, multicolumn CSV files. Each row corresponds to a complete object with multiple fields (column). The HTTP JSON response can match with any of the records. So, I need to perform searching as well in the collection of data. These files are large files (so that I want to load them only once for load test).

What may be a good strategy for me to read assertion data from CSV files only once and access them?

Answer (score 0):

The correct place to load the test data only once is [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/), you can put the code reading the CSV files there.

You can store the objects into JMeter Properties using `props` shorthand like:

```
props.put('object_1`, someValue)
props.put('object_2`, someOtherValue)
```

Example code for the [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion):

```
if (props.values().contains(prev.getResponseDataAsString())) {
    log.info('response data was found')
} else {
    log.info('response data was not found')
}
```

Comment: Problem is - I cannot put objects (or collection) in 'props'. It looks like that 'props' works fine with key-value pair primitive types - string, number, boolean, etc. Is that correct?